# #1103 - Incorrect table name 'employee'

Tags: sql

i'm getting the #1103 - Incorrect table name 'employee'
i searched the mistake code, and i found a question similar to this. they have suggested to delete the white charachters, but I don't have these charachters what can be the mistake?

the code is below, and I already have an employee table which is created before.

```
create table approve(
   employee.ID char(8),
   customer.ID char(8), 
   loanID char(8) primary key,
   foreign key(employee.ID) references employee(ID),
   foreign key(customer.ID) references customer(ID) 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use periods (unquoted) in your field names since it's used for other purposes (for example table/field delimiter) in SQL. You could instead for example use underscore.

```
create table approve(
   employee_ID char(8),
   customer_ID char(8), 
   loanID char(8) primary key,
   foreign key(employee_ID) references employee(ID),
   foreign key(customer_ID) references customer(ID) 
)
```

If you *really* want to use periods which I strongly recommend you don't, you need to quote your table names using the RDBMS' way of quoting, for example in MySQL with backticks;

```
create table approve(
   `employee.ID` char(8),
   `customer.ID` char(8), 
   loanID char(8) primary key,
   foreign key(`employee.ID`) references employee(ID),
   foreign key(`customer.ID`) references customer(ID) 
);
```

Of course, then you'd end up needing to quote your table name *everywhere*, and some tools that do not display the quoting may make things look really strange.